What is the etymology of onani
In the Book of Genesis chapter 38, Judah had a son named Onan.
Onan's story of spilling his seed, leads to the term Onanism.
Onanism is an interpretation of Onan's story.
Regardless of whether there is a of connection to this unproven story, the term Onanism means:

masturbation
coitus interruptus
self-gratification

Is the Japanese word Onani, meaning masturbation, derived from this English term, much like other words:
Coffee->Kohii
Computer->Komputa and so on?
Any time trace to when the word Onani was adopted if so?

Should be a dup Why is the term オナニー written in katakana?

Thank you, I can't read Katakana (Japanese characters?), so maybe I missed the result, which I would have noticed if in Romaji.

I've updated that earlier post to include the romaji in the title as well, so hopefully future searches will be more fruitful (pun unintended ).

The other post doesn't answer the "time trace to when the word Onani was adopted if so?"
